# Generating report from xdebug_get_code_coverage output

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug, behat

We are using BDDs to test our code. With BDDs  you basically have two sets of code, one that runs the tests and the second that is actually executing on your server.

As far as I can tell most of code coverage tools for PHP assume that you are running PHPUnit and then collect stats on your single code base, this issue is discussed in much detail here https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/92.

I've basically given up (maybe incorrectly) on using existing tools and went back to basics. With xdebug I can collect all the stats on the server http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage by injecting the start and stop collection calls at the appropriate places. This will create a huge list of arrays with all the lines that were executed. Now I would like to take this and convert it to a nice report that will actually show code coverage. Unfortunately I don't have the time to build a tool for this. My question is:

Is anyone aware of a tool/way that I can convert the xdebug code coverage output to a report?

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a coverage report? What do you mean by "two sets of code"? Read this again: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/92

Comment: I am afraid the article did not help, please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going from "first principles". Used X-Debug to generate a list of lines being hit and then wrote a script to calculate the coverage. There is also a very nice blog on this here http://qafoo.com/blog/040_code_coverage_with_behat.html